# A quick way to find $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{8-8x}{14+x} + \frac{3x^2+7}{(8x-4)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

I am not sure if there's a quick way to calculate $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{8-8x}{14+x} + \frac{3x^2+7}{(8x-4)^2}$.

I could combine the fractions, but there are three other limits included in the problem I'm doing, and so it seems like there might be a quicker way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple: a theorem asserts that the limit at infinity of a rational function is the limit of the ratio of the leading terms of the numerator and the denominator.

In formula:
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{8-8x}{14+x} =\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{-8x}x=-8,\qquad
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3x^2+7}{(8x-4)^2}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3x^2}{(8x)^2}=\frac{3}{64}.$$

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\frac{8-8x}{14+x} = \frac{8/x-8}{14/x+1} \to -8$$

$$\frac{3x^2+7}{(8x-4)^2} = \frac{3+7/x^2}{(8-4/x)^2} \to \frac{3}{64}$$

when $x \to - \infty$.

Comment: Would you please tell me the name of that rule so I can look it up?

Comment: This is no special rule, I just divided both the numerator and the denominator with $x$ in the first one and with $x^2$ in the second one. I also used that if the limit of the numerator and the limit of the denominator both exist, then the limit of the fraction is equal to their quotient.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{8-8x}{14+x}+\dfrac{3x^2+7}{(8x-4)^2}=\dfrac{\dfrac{8}{x}-8}{\dfrac{14}{x}+1}+\dfrac{3+\dfrac{7}{x^2}}{(8-\dfrac{4}{x})^2}\to-8+\dfrac{3}{8^2}$